# Connecting 2 bones together

Tags: modeling, armature

I need to connect 2 bones together for a game im making.
I only know how to parent them together but dont know how to conect them :/
Any help will be appreciated!
[image: I need to connect these two bones to the middle one][image: Not like this]

Comment: I need to connect the bones to the middle bone in the first image. And in the second image that is not how I want it to be.

Comment: so what's the problem with ctrl P > Connected?

Comment: In unreal engine, a game making engine you can only import armatures, which have the bones conected together. Not with the parent option.

Comment: it's not clear to me what you're trying to do, and what's happening in your pictures, maybe try to reformulate, or maybe someone will understand

Comment: This isn't a criterion in UE4. I imported my own armatures with loose bones and they work fine. But if you want to do this anyway, the horizontal bones are pointing to the wrong direction. In the bone properties if you check in "Connected" for each bone, you will never have loose bones.

Comment: Thank you so much. I recently moved from unity so I am really sorry if Im askikng stupid questions :)